# Update the database table with the same button that is used to insert

Tags: android, android-sqlite, textwatcher

I have a really different situation. I have a form where user fills the data and insert into database. Now in the same form, I need to update his data also. Something like, there is a search user autocomplete text view. When user finds him then the data from database directly fills all the form fields. Now, either he submits data with the same info, if his info has not changed or, if the info has changed, he changes only some of the fields and then press the same button(submit) to update his data. I am doing so because I need to register the user in different particular session. He can register many times with same data. But when his some of the data is changed, I need to update his data but with registering him in the session with new id.

I do not want to provide you my codes here, I just need some technical help, how can I achieve the solution of this problem? If I am not wrong, I am thinking to use TextWatcher. I can implement textwatcher in each edittext form. When the text is changed, somehow the button(submit) that is used to insert get some connection with textwatcher, that it should update the database instead insert.

I am not sure if I am right. Help me please if you have some easy and reliable method to do. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You must have created a method in the Activity or a method in a separate class(I would prefer a separate class for database related methods). And you must keep some registration id or something which should match every time.

Suppose the registration id is named as ID. When you are inserting the data check within that insert method whether this ID matches with any previous records or not. If it matches then do update instead of insert.

Something like:

```
SQLiteDatabase objSqliteDB = DatabaseHelper.openDataBase();
objSqliteDB.beginTransaction();
SQLiteStatement stmtRecCount = objSqliteDB.compileStatement("select count(*) from ID where ID =?");
stmtRecCount.bindString(1, ID);
long count = stmtRecCount.simpleQueryForLong();
if(count != 0)
{
    stmtUpdate.bindString(1, Name);
    . . .
    stmtUpdate.execute();
}
else
{
    stmtInsert.bindString(1, Name);
    . . .
    stmtInsert.executeInsert();
}
```

Add whatever other fields you need to update

> stmtInsert 
>   &
>   stmtUpdate

will be yourinsert and update query

Comment: ** And you must keep some registration id or something which should match every time.** Do you mean _id (AutoIncrement Key)? If it is, how to match the user is the same user with that. Actually that sentence, I do not understand.

Comment: Now I get what do you mean. So this check will be done when the button is clicked. Right??

Comment: Yup when you are submitting the form again, lets hope 5 fields are changed, but how will you know that a previous form has been updated its not a new form, so you must keep a registration id or a form id,its better to keep a separate id, but autoincrement key will also work.